# Как реализовать алгоритм генератора случайного 4-значного числа без повторений знаков?

Tags: java, генерация-случайных-данных

Сейчас я пишу простую программку "Быки и коровы" на java, но у меня возникла проблема. Дело в том, что мне надо сгенерировать случайное 4-х значное число, в котором цифры не должны повторятся, однако, если я просто генерирую случайное значение через for:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] num = new int[4];
num[0] = (int) (Math.random()+ 1 * 9);
for(int i = 0;i < 4; i++) {
   num[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
}
```

то цифры повторяются.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы числа не повторялись?

Comment: Создайте число включающее в себя все цифры от 0 до 9. Перемешайте его с помощью shuffle, а потом получите первые 4 числа

Comment: генерируйте 4 раза по одной цифре, проверяйте, не повторяются ли они. Затем первое a1 * 1000 + a2 * 100 + a3 * 10 + a4. и  готово

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант с проверкой каждого числа:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] num = new int[4];
    int rand = random.nextInt(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        while (!checkOnRepeat(num, rand))
            rand = random.nextInt(10);
        num[i] = rand;
        rand = random.nextInt(10);
    }

    for (int i : num)
        System.out.println(i);
}

public static boolean checkOnRepeat(int[] num, int rand) {
    for (int i : num)
        if (i == rand)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Василий Курагов, ну что, разобрались?

Comment: Да, спасибо, разобрался.